# Compilar vários JS mantendo os nomes originais

Tags: laravel

Pessoal tenho uma pasta dentro do resources chamada js onde tem vários arquivos JS e subpastas com outros JSs. Como eu configuro o Laravel Mix para ele compilar todo o conteúdo da pasta JS inclusive as subpastas para a pasta public/js mantendo os nomes e pastas originais e se possível aplicando o versionamento nos arquivos.
Ex.

> resources/js/teste1.js
>   resources/js/teste2.js
>   resources/js/teste3.js
>   resources/js/temp/teste1.js
>   resources/js/temp/teste2.js

Depois de compilado tem que ficar assim:

> public/js/teste1.js
>   public/js/teste2.js
>   public/js/teste3.js
>   public/js/temp/teste1.js
>   public/js/temp/teste2.js

Obrigado

Comment: Já tentou fazer algo assim? mix.js('resources/assets/js/*.js', 'public/js');

Comment: @DiegoVieira o mix.js não aceita coringas na sua sentença.

Comment: Já tentou o `copyDirectory`?

Comment: @ValdeirPsr então o copyDirectory ele não compila o JS, ele apanas copia como esta para o diretório final. Eu preciso compilar para rodar em todos os browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var fs = require('fs');

// retorna todos os arquivos dentro do diretório dir
let getFiles = function (dir) {
    return fs.readdirSync(dir).reduce((prev, file) => {
        var fullPath = `${dir}/${file}`;
        if (fs.statSync(fullPath).isFile()) {
            // apenas terminados em .js
            if (file.indexOf('.js') === file.length - 3) {
                prev.push(file);
            }
        }   
        else {
            // folder, recurse e retorna subpath junto com arquivo
            prev = prev.concat(getFiles(fullPath).map((f) => file + '/' + f))
        }
        return prev;
    }, []);
};

getFiles('resources/assets/js/').forEach(function(file) {
    mix.js('resources/assets/js/' + file, 'public/js/' + file);
});
```

Resultado:

```
DONE  Compiled successfully in 725ms                                                                                           
13:55:47

              Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
   /js/bootstrap.js   275 kB       0  [emitted]  [big]  /js/bootstrap
         /js/app.js  3.06 kB       1  [emitted]         /js/app
/js/image-resize.min.js  29.9 kB   2  [emitted]     /js/image-resize.min
   /js/temp/test.js  2.95 kB       3  [emitted]     /js/temp/test
   /js/page-html.js  5.79 kB       4  [emitted]     /js/page-html
 /js/calculadora.js  5.85 kB       5  [emitted]         
/js/calculadora
       /css/app.css  7.92 kB       1  [emitted]     /js/ap


$ ls public/js/
app.js  bootstrap.js  calculadora.js  image-resize.min.js  page-html.js  temp
$ ls public/js/temp/
test.js
```

Se seus js não estão em `resources/assets/js` adapte as chamadas para o local desejado.